# Enable OCSP stapling with Freeipa - Apache

Tags: ssl, authentication, certificates, freeipa

I have 3 machines with Centos 7.

I have FreeIPA server installed on the first machine. This serves as a certificate authority in my network; it's my CA.

I have an other machine with FreeIPA client installed.
This one can provide web services for a third machine. It has a certificate generated by the CA.

The third machine doesn't have freeipa installed and makes https requests on the second machine.

I would like to use OCSP stapling.

So I have added the lines following in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` of my 2d machine:

```
SSLUseStapling on  
SSLStaplingCache shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
```

and restarted httpd.

When I make a https request from the third machine with curl it appears **OCSP no response send**.
So i think my CA (the Freeipa server on my first machine) is not well configured.
I tried to make changes in *nss.conf* on the CA and I looked in
`/etc/pki/pki-tomcat/ca/CS.cfg` but I don't succeed to enable ocsp stapling. I haven't any idea.

I add I have checked, in my IPA server, that *ca.ocsp=true* in `/var/lib/pki/pki-tomcat/ca/conf/CS.cfg`.

Can you help me please? I will be very grateful.
Thank you so much.

EDIT:

The certificate of the https server has an Authority info access extension with the ocsp responder's url and the url is correct.
The firewall is disabled.

`openssl ocsp -issuer ca.cert -cert server.cert -text -url http://ipa-ca.mydomain.com/ca/ocsp` gives an ocsp response but the command `openssl s_client -connect myserver.mydomain.com:443 -tls1  -tlsextdebug  -status` gives **ocsp response: no response sent**.

I understand the ocsp responder is ok but the stapling doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you did the `openssl ocsp ...` test *from* `myserver.mydomain.com`, then it looks like the myserver.mydomain.com has connectivity to the OCSP responder.

The next thing to determine is, is the *Apache HTTPS server process* able to use that connectivity? CentOS 7 has SELinux enabled by default, and it has some restrictions to `httpd`. With OCSP stapling, the `httpd` process will need to be able to make outgoing TCP connections to the OCSP responder. To allow that, you will need to do:

```
 setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Without this setting, the `httpd` process will be unable to make outgoing TCP connections: it can only respond to incoming connections. This would certainly prevent making any OCSP requests.

You should also look at the logs of the HTTPS server. If it is logging error messages like:

```
AH02217: ssl_stapling_init_cert: Can't retrieve issuer certificate!
```

then the problem is that the HTTPS server does not have the CA certificate chain for the OCSP responder available, so it cannot verify the authenticity of the response it received from the OCSP responder. To fix that, you'll need to provide the appropriate CA certificate(s) to the HTTPS server using `SSLCertificateFile` or `SSLCertificateChainFile` directives in the HTTPS server configuration. If you use `SSLCertificateFile`, you can just append the PEM-formatted certificates of the relevant intermediate and root CA(s) to the file that contains your HTTPS server certificate.